# Unordered List item <Li>'s not able to retain class when given programatically

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My Problem is that I am trying to change the class of li item when its  item is clicked . I succeed in that but problem is that class is given to li item but its not able to retain class.

My html and jquery is like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {        

            //On Click Event
            $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {

            $("ul.tabs li").removeclass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab                     

        });
    });

</script>

<div class="menu_nav">
     <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="default.aspx"><span>Home Page</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="support.aspx"><span>Support</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.aspx"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="services.aspx"><span>Services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.aspx"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you loose class on postback?

Comment: Something seems wrong here:  $("ul.tabs li").addClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class

Comment: sorry its remove class it got posted here as addClass and problem is same

Answer (score 2):

> $("ul.tabs li").addClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class

You are adding class in above statement you need to use [**removeClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) method instead of add class

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/WMdVv/)**

```
$("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //this will remove active class from all tabs
$(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
```

Comment: sorry its remove class it got posted here as addClass and problem is same

Comment: great work adil but when i click on a particular link it gets class but it prevents from going control to the linked page. Or we can say hyperlink is not working but classes are bieng changed successfully

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but here is a typo:

```
$("ul.tabs li").removeclass("active");
             //   ----^----------------make "c" in caps "C"
```

and make sure to prevent the default behavior of the links otherwise you get your page refreshed.

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // then all your code stuff here
```